# How to test the value and display of a v-text-field?

Tags: testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I'm having an issue trying to test what the contents of a v-text-field object is and it's driving me crazy.  I'm having a bit of trouble following the documentation, so any help is appreciated.

I have 2 files below: time.spec.js and time.vue.  Now, my setup is working as the first test is running just fine ("display provided label").  My second test, however, "display provided time value" is not working.  It boils down to 2 issues:

1: `expect(textFieldElement.value).toContain('11:53');` This fails because `.value` is always ""

2: `expect(textFieldElement.html()).toContain('11:53 AM');` This fails because nothing like this exists in the HTML.

For those that aren't aware, i'm using this setup for the timepicker: https://codepen.io/jasonwilczak/pen/GREXmvo?editors=101

The issue is that it shows `11:53 AM` in the UI but behind the scenes, the data that is return in code is `11:53` and if you did `02:12 PM` it will return `14:12` which is all totally great.  However, I want to have some tests around my wrapper component and I can't figure out, how to test that the UI says `02:12 PM` and the value is `14:12`.  What's even crazier, is that it's all working perfectly fine in my website, but I can't figure out how to test it!

I've messed around with the different methods that are on the docs site for vue and vuetify, but nothing is clicking... I feel like I am missing something really simple, but it's driving me crazy.

```
//time.spec.js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import TimeComponent from './time.vue';

describe('components.time will: ', () => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue();

  beforeEach(() => {
  })

  test('display provided label', () => {
    // mount() returns a wrapped Vue component we can interact with
    const wrapper = mount(TimeComponent, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        label: 'Start Time'
      }
    })
    const textField = wrapper.findComponent({name:'v-text-field'});
    const textFieldText = textField.text();
    expect(textFieldText).toContain('Start Time')
    expect(textFieldText).toContain('EST');
  })
  test('display provided time value', () => {
    let newValue = '';
    const wrapper = mount(TimeComponent, {
      localVue,
      propsData: {
        label: 'Start Time',
        value: '11:53'
      }
     });

    const textField = wrapper.findComponent({name:'v-text-field'});
    const textFieldElement = textField.find('input').element;

    expect(textFieldElement.value).toContain('11:53');
    expect(textFieldElement.html()).toContain('11:53 AM');
  })


//time.vue component
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-text-field v-model="timeData" prepend-icon="access_time" :label="label" type="time" suffix="EST" @change="updated"></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
<script>
  import logger from '../../../utility/logger';

  export default {
    props: [
      'label',
      'value',
      'changeListener',
      'use12hourFormat'
    ],
    data: () => ({
      timeData: ''
    }),
    mounted() {
      if (this.value) this.timeData = this.value;
    },
    methods: {
      updated() {
        logger.log('time.vue.updated()', 'time input text field on change fired');
        if (this.changeListener && typeof this.changeListener == 'function') {
          logger.log('time.vue.updated()', 'handler was passed, sending: ' + this.timeData);
          this.changeListener(this.timeData);
        }
      },
      clear() {
        logger.log('time.vue.clear()', 'clear is executing');
        this.timeData = null;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try casting the return into  and then u can trigger the value

```
expect((<HTMLInputElement>textFieldElement).value).toEqual('11:53')
```